# How to show paths continuously in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I've been googling and searching for an answer to this question. I would like a view where I can see my paths over the image I'm working on (see screenshot)

Anyone that can help me with this?

[image]

Comment: Don't use a fill.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the layer with your paths to outline mode by command+clicking on the layer in the layers panel. If you have your image in another layer you should still be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the path a thickness of 0.5px (or thinner) so that the path shows up.

Comment: That's a workaround that I can use, but I'm actually looking for the solution to see the paths as in the image. I see the paths when selected, but when I work on a new path, the selection goes away and so do the paths.

Comment: @ThomasvanTil you need to give the path a stroke as the answer says. YOu can apply a default stroke then next time you make the path it will be visible, or you can apply the stroke to the layer, then all paths in that layer would have a stroke that you can toggle. Paths that dont have strokes arent supposed to be visible that's kindof the point of the software. Its not really a workaround just the way the sofware works.

Comment: I see, but how do you achieve a view like this then: I see, but how do you achieve a view like this then:

https://imgur.com/a/3Ao2Mko

Comment: @ThomasvanTil yes that is outline mode, your image must be set on a separate layer and that layer set to tomplate (double click on layer to access layer mode)

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure nothing is selected
- Press <kbd>D</kbd> to get the default colors
- Set the front color to none
- Add a stroke width
- Get the **Pen Tool** and start making the path

[image: penttool]